# mySql query error when I try to use and IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm not able to find the error in MySQL query.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 10

When I remove:

```
IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
END IF;
```

Then the query executes fine.

I've tried using tab/space inside my IF statement

```
CREATE EVENT UPLOADTASK
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2019-07-09 00:00:00'
DO
IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
  (1,"TASK1",curdate()-1,NULL),
  (6.5,"TASK2",curdate()-1,NULL),
  (3.0,"TASK3",curdate()-1,NULL),
  (8,"TASK44",curdate()-1,NULL);
END IF;
```

Comment: did the answer helped?

Comment: Yes - it worked, actually. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your `If` inside `Begin End` block

```
CREATE EVENT UPLOADTASK
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2019-07-09 00:00:00'
DO
 BEGIN
    IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN
      INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
      (1,"TASK1",curdate()-1,NULL),
      (6.5,"TASK2",curdate()-1,NULL),
      (3.0,"TASK3",curdate()-1,NULL),
      (8,"TASK44",curdate()-1,NULL);
    END IF;
 END
```